# redirect [no-cache] to a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, reload

i have a list of records and on each record, if I click I go to a different page.

On the 2nd page, i change the status of the record. I change the status on changing a value in the dropdown. when I change the value in the dropdown, i call an api to commit the change.
after the success call I am redirecting users to the list page where records should have changed status value.

this works in all browser but NOT IN I.E (Not even in i.e. 11)

In I.E, when i go to the list page I see the old value untill I press f5 and refresh.

the following code is running when I change the status of my record in the 2nd page.

```
function changeStatus(status)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api call url",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
           // alert("success call");
            window.location = "list url"; // adding a datetime() here, doesn't give me any luck.

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });


}
```

i tried many things, including putting a datetime in the url with no luck.
is there any workaround?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: when I change the dropdown value

Comment: adding a (new) _GET_ in the search of a _URI_ will usually prevent cacheing

Comment: Paul S. - didn't get that?? can you explain a little more plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the cache setting ([jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

```
function changeStatus(status)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api call url",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
           // alert("success call");
            document.location = "list url"; // adding a datetime() here, doesn't give me any luck.

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Stated another way: "Your server fails to specify a proper cache lifetime, so IE is forced to guess at that lifetime. Changing the URL by appending a random number (which is what `cache: false` does) solves the problem by bypassing the cache. You could also set a proper `Cache-Control` directive on your HTTP response and fix the problem the standards-based way.

Comment: @EricLaw Thanks for explaining it, I usually don't have the time to write such a complete answer, your comment is very much appreciated.

Comment: adding cache:false here, doesn't fix the problem. and also interesting thing is when I am in debugging mode, and when it goes to the 'list' page, it doesn't hit the controller code. it just goes to the page as if I pressed the browser 'back' button. It happens only in I.E. Other browser works fine.

Comment: @kandroid Did you try to specify a `contentType` ?

Comment: do you mean in the ajax call?

Comment: hey...it is fixed now. :) I actually had to add cache:false in the list page. not here. However thanks a lot.